# Commerce Kickstart 2 Import Products?

Tags: commerce, importing-exporting

I'm frustrated. I'm trying to import products and sales history to get a Commerce Kickstart 2 store running. I didn't find out how fraught this is until -after- the site was mostly done. The Commerce Kickstart Migrate module and Migrate seem to be incompatible. I've tried upgrading the Migrate module and it throws several PDOExceptions. Does anyone have a solution for taking spreadsheet or SQL data and importing into Commerce products?

Comment: I don't recall having problems using Commerce Migrate (assume [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_migrate) is the one you mean)...could you be more specific about what you've tried and what errors you get?

Comment: Wow. Someone answered!  (Sorry to sound snarky but it looks like the Commerce Guys have left the building.) I went to the Commerce docs and there's reference to a screencast which is missing. It is also suggested to use Commerce Migrate Ubercart. The CMU doc says that in order to use it one needs to upgrade to migrate_d2d and Migrate 2.6 which Kickstart does not support. https://www.drupal.org/node/2187251 So... I'm looking for other options to import Ubercart products. I can use a spreadsheet for basic stuff, but if there are any other recommendations I really want to know ASAP.